# Joomla SEF and Jumi URL output

Tags: php, joomla, joomla-sef-urls, jumi

I'm using jumi at the moment to create custom pages for joomla. However, when i try to use JRoute (eg: JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jumi')) to redirect to a menu item i created for the jumi page, I get the following url http://www.mydomain.com/component/jumi/confirm?ad_code=MDAwMV8wNTgx.(WHERE confirm is my jumi alias)

My question now is: how can i get rid of the "/component/jumi/" statement in the url. (ie: http://www.mydomain.com/confirm?ad_code=MDAwMV8wNTgx)

Comment: Possibility see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887099/remove-component-part-from-sef-url-menu-item-not-completely

Comment: I still can't do it. I think its different for jumi. What i'm creating now is not a custom component. I'm using a script i write using joomla and creating a menu item with joomla for the jumi application. I'm still getting the component dirname line

Comment: which joomla version ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

1. In your Menu Item Manager (Menus, Select a Menu) .
2. Create a new Menu item, Select your Component from the Menu Type Options
3. Enter in the Menu Item Details Title and Alias.  The title will now be the text shown as the link and will remove the /component/ from your URL.

The above tips is taken from [here](http://www.cmsmind.com/joomla-remove-component-from-url/)

Comment: Yes. I understand. I created the menu and i can access the page as well. So if i were to go to http://www.mydomain.com/confirm?ad_code=MDAwMV8wNTgx, the page will be displayed.

Comment: My problem now is when i tried linking(<a href="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=8').'">) or submitting a form with (action="'.JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_jumi&view=application&fileid=8').'") pointing to this page. I get the component thingy out again.